# GameScene not rendering correctly on iPhone 5/5S

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to show a background image in my GameScene. When I go to run it, it displays fine on every device except an iPhone 5/5S. Below are screenshots showing what it looks like on an iPhone 4s and an iPhone 5 from the simulator.

[image: iPhone 4s Screenshot]

[image: iPhone 5 Screenshot]

This is how I show the background image:

```
    // set background image
    let backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg")
    backgroundImage.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height/2)
    addChild(backgroundImage)
```

I've tested it on the simulator and actual devices and still have this problem.

Comment: that sometimes happens if you don't add launch images for all screen sizes

Comment: That was it! Although I only had launch images for the iPhone 6/6 plus. Thank you!

Comment: that is exactly what happens when you dont add launch images,  it treats the device as an iphone 4/4s app for compatibility purposes